# ingress rule for jenkins

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am working on a setup where I can access different installations of Jenkins based on the path.
ie /prod takes to production Jenkins and /some other to some other Jenkins.

I create following ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  labels:
    app: jenkins
  namespace: jenkins
  name: jenkins-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /login
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: Authorization, origin, accept
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: GET, OPTIONS
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    # - host: "jenkins"
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: jenkins-svc
              servicePort: 8080
            path: /prod
```

using above I am able to access Jenkins on /prod but clicking on any link navigates me away from Jenkins.(the issue is that after clicking on any link /prod is not appended to it and  things do not work)

What annotations I have to use to make this work.

Comment: check this. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an annotation like -

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /prod
```

As per [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/), if your server's root path is different than `/` then the `app-route` annotation will treat /prod as your root path.

Answer (score 0):

as you want to access different Jenkins based on the path you can something like

```
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: swagger-ui
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    name: swagger-staging-ingress
  spec:
    rules:
    - host: developer.test.example.io
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: svc-1
            servicePort: 80
          path: /prod(/|$)(.*)
        - backend:
            serviceName: svc-2
            servicePort: 80
          path: /stag(/|$)(.*)
```

if any request to `developer.test.example.io/stag` redirected to `svc-2` if `/prod` it will be redirected to `svc-1`.

Comment: Thanks, Harsh I will try the same. One ques, what does $2 means in nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2

Comment: Captured groups are saved in numbered placeholders, chronologically, in the form $1, $2 ... $n. These placeholders can be used as parameters in the rewrite-target annotation.

Comment: you can read more at  : https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/